# Unexpected overflow result from a function when inputting max uint256

Tags: function

I am looking at the following function `tickUpper` that is supposed to retrieve the 24 bits of a 256 bit number beginning at bit 208. It's cast to an int24 because it interfaces with uniswap ticks.

I tested it using the max uint256 as self, expecting to get the max int24 since all the bits in the number are 1. Instead I am getting -1. Does anyone know why? I know this can happen from an overflow.

```
function tickUpper(uint256 self) internal pure returns (int24) {
        unchecked {
            return int24(int256(self >> 208));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not an overflow, that is normal because you need to consider you are mixing `uint` and `int` values.

The max positive integer for an `int24` is actually `2^23 - 1 = 8.388.607 = 0x7fffff`, because you are using the most significant bit - the first one - to define the sign. Side note: if a byte has its first bit equal to zero, its hex representation is equal or below `0x7f`.

So, `int24` values go like this:

```
0x000000 =          0
0x000001 =          1
0x000002 =          2
0x000003 =          3
...
0x7fffff =  8.388.607
0x800000 = -8.388.608
0x800001 = -8.388.607
0x800002 = -8.388.606
...
0xfffffd =         -3
0xfffffe =         -2
0xffffff =         -1
```

I don't know what you use that function for, but the following is its flow:

- you send the max `uint256` (`0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`)
- that value is shifted right by `208` bit, so you are pushing 26 `0x00` bytes from the left (`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffffffff = 1.099.511.627.775`)
- then you convert from `uint256` to `int256`, and nothing happens at the bit level. In this case, you still have the same positive number because the first bit is `0`
- then you covert to `int24`, so you keep only the three bytes to the right, and you end up with `0xffffff`
- `0xffffff` is actually `-1` in `int24`